# Impedimento para sumar dos variables

Tags: python

Estoy teniendo un problema con mi código en Python. Es sobre manejo de eventos. En el código deseo sumar cifra_1 con cifra_2, pero me sale un mensaje de error.

Estas cantidades las obtengo haciendo click sobre una imagen de puntos insertados en un subplot.

Creo que la secuencia de clicks no me deja sumar las variables.

¿Por que no me deja sumar normalmente python?

¿Alguna ayuda?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor, Button
from numpy import random
import math

clicks = 1

x, y = random.rand(2, 100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p, = plt.plot(x, y, 'o')

cursor = Cursor(ax,
                horizOn=True, # Controls the visibility of the horizontal line
                vertOn=True, # Controls the visibility of the vertical line
                color='red',
                linewidth=1.0
            )
def onclick(event):
    x1, y1 = event.xdata, event.ydata

    global clicks

    if clicks % 2 == 0:

        if clicks == 2:

                print(x1)

        number_clicks = ['0']

        for i in range(len(number_clicks[0])):

            if clicks == 4:

                cifra_1 = x1

                print(cifra_1)

            if clicks == 6:

                cifra_2 = x1

                print(cifra_2)

            if clicks == 8:

                suma = cifra_1 + cifra_2

                print(suma)

    clicks = clicks + 1 

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', 
onclick)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te falta definir las variables antes de la función, yo le las inicie con un valor de 0, pero tu puedes hacerlo con el valor que te sirva, te dejo un trozo de codigo con la linea editada como ejemplo:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor, Button
    from numpy import random
    import math

    cifra_1, cifra_2 = 0, 0 #LINEA QUE FALTA
    clicks = 1

    x, y = random.rand(2, 100)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    p, = plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
    #RESTO DEL CODIGO
```

Luego dentro de la funcion di que dichas varibles son globales y estaria listo.

```
    def onclick(event):
            x1, y1 = event.xdata, event.ydata

            global clicks, cifra_1, cifra_2 #LINEA EDITADA
            print(clicks)
```